# Funciones de una tabla dinamica en react

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

Tengo una tabla que se llena dinamicamente, en dicha tabla tengo un estado que se cambia a true o false y con el cual quiero habilitar o deshabilitar un select pero al ser dentro de una tabla dinamico se habilitan y deshabilitan todos los selects.

Mi tabla es la siguiente:

```
{

  this.state.room.map((item, index) =>

        <tbody key={index}>
            <tr>
               <td><input checked={this.state.checked[index]} onChange={this.Handlecheck} type="checkbox"></input></td>
                  <th scope="row" >{item.room_category_desc}</th>
               <td >
                  <select  id={"select"+idx+index} className="form-control form-control-sm col-sm" disabled={this.state.checked ? false : true} >
                      <option>Select</option>
                         { item.bed.map((bedtype)=>
                      <option key={bedtype} value={bedtype}>{bedtype == "K" ? "King" : bedtype == "D" ? "Double": ""}</option>
                   )
                  }
                   </select>
             </td>
             <td >$653.31</td>
             <td >$4,573.20</td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
    )
 }
```

```
Handlecheck(checked){
            this.setState({checked: checked.target.checked});
    }
```

Actualmente con el checkbox se habilitan y deshabilitan todos al mismo tiempo y no se como hacer para que se haga solo en la fila que estos presionando el checkbox y al mismo tiempo des habilitar los demas checbox de manera que el usuario solo pueda habilitar una fila de la tabla

Saludos

Comment: Que tienes en tu metodo `Handlecheck`? Lo que miro es que en esta linea `disabled={this.state.checked ? false : true} ` no estas acciendo a `this.state.checked[index]` como lo haces en el input, `checked={this.state.checked[index]}`, se supone que es un arreglo

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario pero eso ya lo había hecho y no funciono.

Comment: agregue el codigo de la funcion